# How to set checkbox value to 1 on checked and 0 on unchecked?

Tags: angular

I am working on angular 4 application and using reactive forms.

I want to save checkbox value in 0/1 not in true/false. Right now when I check my checkbox I got true and on un-check I got false but I want 1 on checked and 0 on unchecked.

Comment: `let conversion = input.checked ? 1: 0;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use ngModel

```
  [ngModel]="value.selected == 1 ? true : value.selected == 0 ? false : null" (ngModelChange)="value.selected = $event ? 1 : 0"
```

you can also check for the value at form submission in reactive form and map the values to `1 : 0`

**Update**

`this.form.get('checked') ? 1:0`

Comment: I don't want to convert the values by field name because in some time I don't know the field names.

Comment: @LakhvirSinghthen use ngModel that is the best bet , but reactives forms ngmodel dosent work out its not advisable to use that . how come you dnt know control names

Comment: Because controls name are dynamic and created at run time from API.

Comment: @LakhvirSingh then get the whole form and segregate it , or best it at submit you just update by checking the value .have false as 0 and true as 1. i updated the ans

Answer (score 1):

Just add it:

```
 (change)="yourCheckBoxModelName = $event.target.checked ? 1: 0"
```

Like:

```
 <input type="checkbox" 
   (change)="isCheckModel = $event.target.checked ? 1: 0"
   name="isCheckModel"
   [(ngModel)]="isCheckModel">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make use of `(ngModelChange)` to map the value, if you're using `template-driven` forms.

```
[ngModel]="!!myValue" (ngModelChange)="myValue = $event ? 1 : 0"
```

and in component template:

```
public myValue: number = 0;
```

If you're using `ReactiveFormsModule` you map the value afterwards:

```
this.myValue = +this.myForm.get('myCheckboxControl');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the boolean in the reactive form and instead 'translate' it to 0/1 in the submit and in the init of the form.
Init form (if edit)

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
   'myCheck':new FormControl(presetData.someValue===1)
})
```

Submit

```
const dataToSubmitInPost={
    theCheck:this.form.value.myCheck?1:0
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
this.form.get('checked').value ? 1:0
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//s.tk/meta/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post.